# Function in declaration file in packed node project vs. in local TS project

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, types

I set up a declaration file for a node library so that I'll be able to consume it in my TS project.

Initially, when tested locally on the TS project, my .d.ts file looked something like the following which worked when was in the TS project

```
declare module 'my_module' {
    export function myFunction(value?: string) any;
}
```

I then added the .d.ts declaration file to the node library, packed it, and imported it into the TS project. When I try to access myFunction as such-

```
import * as testing from '<my_node_project>';

testing.myFunction("foo");
```

I'm getting an error that TypeError: testing.myFunction is not a function

Is there a reason why this is working locally but not when packed?